# angular.min.js:127 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I keep get this error when i try to learn angularJs.. help me please. Am new in this kind of technology, I want to output list of students to the table like shown below.

Thanks!

my studentController.js

```
        var studentApp = angular.module("studentApp", []);

studentApp.controller("studentController", ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.students = [
        {name: 'Innocent Tanga', city: 'Mwanza', age: 45},
        {name: 'Zena John', city: 'Tabora', age: 15},
        {name: 'Noel Toyi', City: 'Tanga', age: 78},
        {name: 'Nicole Tofla', city: 'Mwanza', age: 45},
        {name: 'Jua Nickson', city: 'Toa', age: 25},
        {name: 'Pass Toboa', city: 'Iringa', age: 15},
    ];
}]);
```

index.html

````
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Angular - Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="studentApp" ng-controller="studentController">

        <div>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td>Age</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
                    <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ student.city }}</td>
                    <td>{{ student.age }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

</div>

<script src="../cdn/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="studentController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 `ng-app` directives used in the html and this causes the error. The first one in html tag is the first found in the document and fails to instatiate the app `studentApp` module properly.

Remove `ng-app` from the div tag and place it in the `html` tag as below:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="studentApp">
```

> ...only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application...

Read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Working demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pLfuaeyg/)

Comment: +1 Good catch. If the entire window will always be the one app, I'd recommend leaving it on the html tag and removing it from the div (just because it allows you to bind stuff to the head)

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias you are 100% right, it is the most common to place it in html tag. I will edit with a better explanation thanks!